# Sending Custom Objects to an asp.net webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, web-services

So I want to send a custom object to an asp.net 4.0 Webservice.
I have been sending a bunch of individual parameters but i want to start reusing some code so I'd like to do something like

```
    [WebMethod(Description = "Testing Sending Object In")]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public bool COT(CodeWithMessage CWM)
    {
...
```

where the class for CodeWithMessage is

```
namespace UserSite
{
    namespace General
    {
        public class CodeWithMessage
        {
            public int iCode { get; set; }
            public string sMessage { get; set; }
            public CodeWithMessage()
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The webservice defines the input as

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <soap:Body>
        <COT xmlns="http://localhost">
          <CWM>
            <iCode>int</iCode>
            <sMessage>string</sMessage>
          </CWM>
        </COT>
      </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

I tried passing the webservice the following json

```
      var postdata = { "iCode": -5, "sMessage": "BlogName " }
```

I get back an Internal Server Error [500]

> {"Message":"Invalid JSON primitive: iCode."

Do I need to wrap this up somehow to indicate it is part of this object? I tried

```
{"__type":"UserSite.General.CodeWithMessage","iCode":-5,"sMessage":"Blog Name Already Exists"}
```

Which is what CodeWithMessage returns from another webservice that sends it instead of receiving it.

Comment: Is there some reason you're not using WCF instead of the legacy ASMX technology?

Comment: hrm.  I guess because I have no knowledge of how WCF works or that it even replaced ASXM.  I guess I'll have to start looking into this. Thanks

Comment: Seriously? WCF was released with .NET 3.0 in 2006.

Comment: Yeah.  I took 5 years out of software development to help my family with their business and I have recently jumped back in.  2006 would be precisely when I left the field.

Comment: I would highly recommend looking into WCF.  Here is a good reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/dd939784.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Your error says that you Json is wrong you need to check the json string you are passing to the webservice.

its may be like

```
var postdata = { 'iCode': '-5', 'sMessage': 'BlogName' }
```

check the jSon String example : http://www.json.org/js.html on jSon site........